# How to protect Hindi character combination

Tags: extended-characters, hindi

I have been trying obtain exact characters using XeLaTeX in the following code:

```
%!TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hindi}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Arial Unicode MS}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{english}{The word University in Hindi is written like this}: विश्वविद्यालय

\end{document}
```

The intended combination of Hindi characters is displayed in TeXworks nicely but the output after running the code is changed exactly similar to that of one as seen in the above code.

I want to have the output as highlighted in the below image. [image: snapshot example]

Comment: Is there any reason you're using Arial Unicode instead of a font designed for Devanagari?

Comment: I tried Devanagari package too following examples provided by others. Couldn't get the same.

Comment: I think the problem might be your font, if I use (for example) Siddhanta or Lohit Devanagari, everything works for me using your code

Comment: I also notice with suspicion "after running the code is changed exactly similar to that of one as seen in the above code", on my computer, विश्वविद्यालय displays correctly in the code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't read Hindi, so I can't tell if this is correct, but this seems to be a font problem (as Au101 notes too). Here's something testing with 4 different fonts.  Are the last three  examples correct?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hindi}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\hindifont[Script=Devanagari]{Devanagari MT}
\newfontfamily\itf[Script=Devanagari]{ITF Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\noto[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\shree[Script=Devanagari]{Shree Devanagari 714}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{english}{The word University in Hindi is written like this}: 

\Huge विश्वविद्यालय

\itf विश्वविद्यालय

\noto विश्वविद्यालय

\shree विश्वविद्यालय
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In fact, I tried this too. It still doesn't give me what you get on my machine. In your case, two characters in two places even got separated.

Comment: @Khaaba Sorry but I don't understand your comment. Is the output I show correct and not what you get, or is this output not correct? (Not knowing Hindi, it's hard to tell what is expected and what is not.)

Comment: Sorry, I felt asleep. Your output is still incorrect. Output word in the code as well as in the highlighted image are same, however, I would like to have what is seen on the image.

Comment: First one has a problem. However, I have been looking for the last(fourth) option. I was trying to make a letterhead of my own actually. Thanks million Mr. Alan!